# How to express regain/recover/pickup an old project

Tags: word-choice

Assuming that one hasn't worked on a project for a while. Now, she wants to work on the same project again and learn what she has forgotten. How should we describe such kind of activity? I guess it could be:

1. Regain previous progress
2. Recover previous progress
3. Pickup previous progress
   ...

Thank you!

Comment: I like _resume_; NOAD says: **resume** (v.) _begin to do or pursue (something) again after a pause or interruption_. As for _pickup_, I might say, "Pick up where I left off" – that's a relatively common expression. In that context, though, _pick up_ is a phrasal verb and should be spelled as two words.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Yes. Resume is the word I am looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resume**.  The word you're looking for is **resume**.

example: I will resume this project after lunch.

You can also say **restart**, though restart the project assumes it's been closed down/ finished as opposed to having been put on a break.  **Resume** works for both scenarios.